# How do i start activity when screen goes off?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have an application which is doing its work only when devices screen goes off. I have set up  broadcast receiver (`Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`) and it works fine. I got record in my LOGCAT always when devices screen goes off. So far so good.

My `onReceive` code from ACTION_SCREEN_OFF uses some code calculating stuff, and all executes fine (When screen goes off). So far so good.

At the end of my `onReceive` code i'm starting new activity, but the `onCreate` of targeting activity is NOT always executing. (For example on my HTC Desire 2.3.7 works fine. On HTC Wildfire S 2.3.5, Xperia Arc S 2.3.4 it does not execute, and on Samsung Galaxy ACE 2.2.1 , it depends. Sometimes is executing sometimes isn't). My LOGCAT shows that `onReceive` executed till the end but Activity was not started. I'm using following code to starting this activity:

```
Intent startH_Activity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HandleActivity.class);
        startH_Activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startH_Activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(startH_Activity);
```

**The important things to note:**

- I said that on some phones mentioned above it doesn't work. Well its not working immediately, like it should (when SCREEN_OFF fires ). Always activity starts like.. 10-15 minutes after screen went off (which is not acceptable)
- When screen goes off and activity does not start , if I press POWER button on device it immediatelyfires off my target activity and app is working like normal. (again this is not acceptable. It should fire automatically).
- When ANY device is connected to the PC it works like it should. Activity starts immediatelyafter screen goes off.

After reading a lot of Stack Overflow I realized that this is because MAYBE device goes to sleep. That's why it works like normal if i press POWER button, or Wakes up automatically after 10-15min because it synchronizes or something. So I used WAKELOCK.

```
//OnCreate Service
powMan = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
wake = powMan.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");

//OnReceive (screen goes off)
wake.acquire();
```

But still without a success. (Am i doing wrong?) Even wake lock is acquired my activity won't show up on these devices.

**Basically what I'm asking. How do i open usual activity when screen goes off? Or at least how to turn screen ON if activity won't start (remember, pressing on power button shows up my activity**

I would really need some help now, because I'm getting really frustrated about this. Thank you for help.

Comment: screen off! referring to screen lock? http://chandan-tech.blogspot.in/2010/10/handling-screen-lock-unlock-in-android.html

Comment: Actually yes. I think all devices locks when screen goes off.

Answer (score 0):

You should be starting Service instead of Activity when screen goes off.

Comment: I need activity to display some data to the user, which i cannot do in service.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be doing that on SCREEN_OFF. User is in control of the device and only them should start Activities with their fingers (or voice; or brain waves).

Comment: So android devices don't have alarm clock or something by your opinion? Alarm clock is working on the same principle as my app. It wakes phone from sleep and shows an activity (Alarm clock shows activity which user chooses what he will do: Disable alarm, snooze..etc)

Comment: Then read about [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). You haven't said anything about clocks in your question.

Comment: Wow, this is bizarre.  So I have an activity whose sole purpose is to watch for the screen to go to sleep, then watch for proximity alerts or the screen to wake up, and keep track of when each of these events occurs and display the result when the screen comes back on.  It seems like there is nothing about this that should require the added complexity of a service, and yet the fact that onStop is being called on my app as soon as the screen goes off (but only if I got from API level 10 to 11) seems to necessitate it!

Answer (score 0):

I would register yet another broadcast receiver and start the Activity when screen goes on (`Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON`).

Two issues:

1) How do you pass data from one receiver to another? What comes to my mind is either starting a Service or saving the information to a file (or shared preferences).

2) What happens if you have two events that must start an Activity? (E.g. "something started" and "something finished".) You must resolve this, either showing both events or just the latest one.

Note that the user can turn the screen on and off without unlocking the screen (`Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT`), and that if the phone is configured not to lock the screen, `Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT` does not happen.